Network error:kex_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort banner exchange (SSH)
I met this issue while trying to clone a repo in a gitlab private server, so I added verbosity and tried to connect to it first here is the output
$ ssh -i test -T -vvvv git@gitlab.aicrowd.com
OpenSSH_9.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1u  30 May 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/c/Users/****/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/c/Users/****/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "gitlab.aicrowd.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup gitlab.aicrowd.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.aicrowd.com [*.*.*.*] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 4 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file test type 0
debug1: identity file test-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.3
kex_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort
banner exchange: Connection to *.*.*.* port 22: Software caused connection abort

I am able to ping the server, I tried this with another machine it worked, I tried to disable firewall but still didn't work.

Fixed your formatting. You might be getting/using the wrong address, but we can't tell because you've withheld it. I connect okay 3.127.191.224 and 3.68.10.87 though of course I can't authenticate (login).
